# In IBM Domino, how can you retrieve Java Class files from Agents and Script Libraries

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Java Agents and Script Libraries in IBM Domino have a unique container format. It's not clear how to extract specifically the **class** files from those containers, or where in Domino Designer to extract/export the class files.

How to do this?

Comment: `JAR` files are just `ZIP` files, so just use your favourite decompressor. Otherwise, please describe your requirements more thoroughly.

Comment: This has to do with IBM/Lotus Domino, which stores Java source and classes in peculiar ways inside its database, and it's not merely a matter of expanding a jar file.

Comment: I agree, this is not too broad or as simple as noted. You need to know Domino Designer to understand. Please re-open!

Comment: Jesse, you are right
Can you let me know how to re-open this post

Comment: In any event, the way to do this is to open the Java agent or script library in Designer, then go to the Navigator view (Window -> Show Eclipse Views...). In there, there will be a stub project for the Java element, and you can right-click on the "bin" dir in there and do Export -> File System to extract the class files.

Comment: this question and answer by Jesse above are pretty helpful and important for people working with IBM Domino. Please re-open this question.

Answer (score 2):

A the way to do this is to open the Java agent or script library in Designer, then go to the Navigator view (Window -> Show Eclipse Views...). In there, there will be a stub project for the Java element, and you can right-click on the "bin" dir in there and do Export -> File System to extract the class files.